# Submit the div content which is outside the form

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc, web-frontend

I have the below structure in cshtml.

```html
@using (Html.BeginForm(ActionName, ControllerName, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "my-form", @role = "form", @class = "form-horizontal" }))
{
  <!-- panels list -->
}

<div id="outside-form">
  <panel1>
    textbox here...
  </panel>
<div>
```

When the form is submit, how can I get the textbox value from `#outside-form`? Is there any way to include this value in that form?

As the design has to be in this way I can't copy this `div` to the main `form`.

Comment: Hook to the `submit` event of the form and use `$('#outside-form input').val()` to get the value you want. You will then need to send the form data using AJAX as you manually need to append the value. If you want a specific example, please add the actual HTML output to the question.

Comment: you can use `ajax` for this

Comment: I am not sure why we need ajax for this, just run a javascript method on submit event, which creates a hidden input inside the form, append the value of the input element outside the form to the hidden element and done.

Comment: Right, it worked values are getting passed to controller, but the DataAnnotation rules are not displaying on the textboxes, even though validations are happening.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: works for textbox, but for DropdownListFor(m => m.DropDownModel.Id), can't have this as hidden value, as dropdownproperty mapping to another class called DropDownModel.